# Binary Rejected once again. How to do?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I did below changes in my code on every path but once again the Binary was rejected.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:photoPath];
[URL setResourceValue:@(YES) forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
```

**1) First Rejection** :

> On launch and content download, your app stores 38+ MB on the user's
>   iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

**2) Second Time Rejection :**

> On launch and content download, your app stores 17+ on the user's
>   iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

Please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using iCloud wrongly. See this by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/iCloud.html

> Respect the user’s iCloud space. It’s important to remember that iCloud is a finite resource for which users pay. You should use iCloud for storing information that users create and understand, and avoid using it to store app resources or content that you can regenerate. Also, note that when the user’s iCloud account is active, iCloud automatically backs up the contents of your app’s Documents folder. To avoid using up too much of the user’s space, it’s best to be picky about the content you place in the Documents folder.

Use minimal amount of iCloud space and avoid using iCloud to store resources and other data which you can reproduce later, in iCloud space.